Is there any possible way to get SQL Server to do something after a transaction commit?
We were exploring whether it was possible to employ a trigger on a SQL Server table to capture if a field changed, and subsequently send a notification to a web service or a message queue, using a .NET module.
There are two sticking points: the first is that if we send the notification whilst the transaction is in progress, the recipient, if it needs to read the data from the database, will potentially not find the data if the transaction has not been committed yet.
The second is that if the transaction fails and is rolled back, we would not have wanted to have sent the notification anyway.
It would seem that both could be achieved if SQL Server had a trigger ability "post commit" but I do not believe such a thing exists.
Is there any alternative way to achieve this?

A simple but similar solution to Mark Sowul's answer might be to use Query Notifications in the .NET module to subscribe to data changes on the table in question.
Basically, you write a query that returns the data you want to monitor for changes, then execute that query in .NET with a SqlDependency tied to the command.
When the underlying data changes, a notification is sent back to the calling application advising of the data change. The app can then take the appropriate action.
This is essentially what Mark is suggesting with Service Broker, except the Query Notification functionality in .NET handles the heavy lifting with Service Broker queues, messages etc for you.
There are some caveats with Query Notifications, particularly around restrictions on the underlying query, but this may suit your purpose.

Can combine with David's comment: 1. have a trigger that inserts pending events into a separate "queued events" table.  2. have a SqlDependency tagged to that separate table that kicks off a "BEGIN TRANSACTION --> DELETE ... OUTPUT --> send the notifications --> COMMIT" loop.

It'd be a heavy lift, but I'll throw it out there: you could use service broker.  Service broker is a message queueing system within SQL server, and importantly its SQL statements are transactional.  So if you SEND a message within the transaction, it will not be visible to the outside world until the transaction commits.
On the C# side, you can WAITFOR / RECEIVE and upon receiving the messages, relay to the web service or external message queue.  You won't be able to RECEIVE the messages until the transaction commits and therefore the changes are visible.
Service broker is a powerful but complicated tool with a lot of boilerplate.  Remus Rusanu has a lot of material if you want to go down that path, but in a nutshell:

You should have two QUEUEs, one for each side of the CONVERSATION
The SQL process in your example (which we will call the initiator) would BEGIN DIALOG CONVERSATION and
SEND MESSAGE (as part of the transaction you are describing).

There's more and this will get tricky, but stand by


The C# (which we will call the target) should be using WAITFOR / RECEIVE on its QUEUE.  BEGIN
TRANSACTION, RECEIVE the messages, do what you need to do, then END
DIALOG and COMMIT

The target of the CONVERSATION must be the one
to END DIALOG first (it sends an "end dialog" message to the initiator's
queue)
Note the transactionality: you RECEIVE the message and
operate on it within a transaction -- if the process fails,
ROLLBACK and you will get the message again next time.  By default, if there are too many consecutive ROLLBACKs, the queue will be disabled (POISON_MESSAGE_HANDLING)

Additionally, the target C# will not see any message until the initiator SQL transaction (#2) COMMITs




Okay, so back to the first queue.  You should have a simple activation procedure,
which will wake up when it receives the aforementioned "end dialog"
message, and it simply responds by doing its own END DIALOG.  Now
both ends of the conversation are completed and everything will get
cleaned up.

This is all similar to Remus's "fire and forget" layout: https://rusanu.com/2006/04/06/fire-and-forget-good-for-the-military-but-not-for-service-broker-conversations/

Also you can simply insert a row into a table, and have a background process send the messages and delete the rows.  This is what Service Broker does under the covers.  You won't get blocking destructive reads and near-instant activation without Service Broker.  But if you can tolerate the latency of a polling loop, it's a simple solution.  See eg: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3641703/using-sql-server-as-a-db-queue-with-multiple-clients

Sounds like Change Data Capture (CDC).
Changes are logged and published to a queue.  You can subscribe to the queues and do whatever you need to.
Note that you do not have to alter any of your transactions or procedures to take advantage of the change being logged, just register an interest in any of the data you are trying to track.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/track-changes/about-change-data-capture-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16


The second is that if the transaction fails and is rolled back, we would not have wanted to have sent the notification anyway

It sounds to me like what you may be seeking is transactional consistency between multiple contexts.
SQL engines provide a relatively easy, built-in facility for transaction control, and for that reason people often mis-apprehend the complexity and subtlety of how this facility works, and the difficulty of reproducing something for themselves.
Unless you're an expert in the field on a well-funded technology project - I'm definitely not in this regard - there will invariably be significant defects and failure cases in any algorithm you design for yourself.
The usual context for these kinds of questions is not from an expert on a well-funded project, but from a relative amateur casually (and often single-handedly) trying to cobble together an arbitrary mixture of closed-source, third-party technologies.
In this way, if I'm inferring the additional requirement of transactional consistency correctly, the answer to your question is that what you're seeking to do isn't practically possible. You should expect a self-made solution to have subtle defects.
Even if a database commits a transaction, there can be an implicit form of rollback when hardware fails and the database is recovered from a backup. The SQL engine is designed to restore to an internally-consistent moment in the past, but your other connected systems won't be orchestrated in this restore.
My advice would be to consider whether your solution can tolerate some inconsistency. If it can, just fire the trigger and forget about rollbacks. If not, cancel your plans and forget about the whole development.
If it can tolerate some inconsistency, others have already mentioned techniques that can avoid external notifications occuring before commit-time, and can time-shift the notification being attempted until after commit-time, but solving that problem doesn't intrinsically solve transactional consistency concerns across the whole system.

Thanks. I am not chasing perfect transactional consistency, and restoring from a backup is a problematic case for any distributed system. But this is one of those situations where we should not let perfect be the enemy of good, and for the 99% case (perhaps even higher), simply being able to avoid messages being sent until transaction commit time is a reasonable approach I think.

@Kevmeister68, cor, you accept defects at a rate of 1 in every 100 and consider that good? Regards backups, the problem is that when disaster strikes, you don't want your workload multiplied at that very moment by many consequential failures, outages, and corruptions.

I'm not sure I understand this take. Firstly it takes 99% as a literal value, and second, it seems to paint all "defects" with one severe brush. If indeed 1 time out of 100 an event is published that a record changed, but it didn't actually change (so the subscriber won't see any difference), is that worth constructing an excessively complex system to avoid?  And how does it relate to restoring a database?  Indeed, a properly "available" distributed system, in which each dependent service has a copy of the data it needs and subscribes to changes, would seem to work just fine with this setup.

Perhaps this is simply a case where everyone is saying the same thing in different ways.  Put another way: if the "defect" is that a change event is not received by a subscriber, that is much more problematic than a spurious change event is received by a subscriber.  Hence the "joke" about the two hard problems in distributed systems (2. exactly-once delivery, 1. in-order delivery, 2. exactly-once delivery) (https://twitter.com/mathiasverraes/status/632260618599403520)

@MarkSowul, I'm just remarking that 99% is not typically regarded as a "good" standard (of reliability, accuracy, etc.) in computing. The problem with database restores is that it's an example of a "change" which subscription mechanisms often don't cope with, yet these are exactly the kind of crisis situations where you don't want a restore of the main database to suddenly cause lots of peripheral or connected systems to malfunction or corrupt because the previously notified changes have been rolled back (including primary key allocations, etc.)

@Steve, you've taken my comment way too literally. The "99% case" is a figure of speech. I don't know the exact number, 99, 99.9, 99.99, 99.999 etc. I do know it won't be 100% over any "long enough" period of time. Perhaps I should have spoken about the "nearly always" case rather than an explicit number. And yes, in my case a false positive (an extraneous message) would not be a big deal, but a missed message would represent a loss of data synchronisation at the receiving system, like any loosely coupled message-oriented system.

@Kevmeister68, it's not that I'm holding you to a specific percentage or interpreting you literally, I just have a suspicion that you're embarking on something that is difficult to make reliable, at the same time as not having a clear idea about reliability. You'd be surprised how many people start by making decisions about the technologies to be used, the architecture, etc., without even considering reliability much. On synchronisation, duplicate notifications from master to slave are the least of the difficulties.
